# Passar números da entrada para matriz em Python

Tags: python, algoritmo, matriz, estrutura-de-dados, grafo

Estou fazendo um exercício sobre grafos bipartidos, no qual a entrada é dada na seguinte forma:

```
6
2 4 5
1 3
2 3 5
1 0
2 2 1
1 1
```

Sendo 6 (o número da primeira linha) o número de linhas a serem lidas, e as outras linhas são sobre os vértices que possuem ligação, na forma:

```
[Número de linhas/vértices]
[Vértice 1] [Vértice X ligado a V1] [Vértice Y ligado a V1]
[Vértice 2] [Vértice X ligado a V2] [Vértice Y ligado a V2]
[Vértice 3] [Vértice X ligado a V3] [Vértice Y ligado a V3]
[Vértice 4] [Vértice X ligado a V4] [Vértice Y ligado a V4]
.
.
.
```

Eu vou utilizar matriz de adjacência para representar isso e utilizar um algoritmo, então preciso transformar essa entrada em uma matriz. Como posso fazer isso?

A entrada acima gera a matriz de adjacência abaixo (os números depois do # são só pra ilustrar):

```
#           0 1 2 3 4 5
g.graph = [[0,0,0,0,1,1], #0
           [0,0,0,1,0,0], #1
           [0,0,0,1,0,1], #2
           [1,0,0,0,0,0], #3
           [0,1,1,0,0,0], #4
           [0,1,0,0,0,0]] #5
```

Outro exemplo:

```
10
3 1 3 5
2 6 8
2 8 4
1 2
4 0 2 6 8
2 3 7
1 1
2 6 2
1 1
3 1 2 3
```

Que deve ser representado na matriz:

```
#            0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
g.graph =  [[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0], #0
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0], #1
            [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0], #2
            [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], #3
            [1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0], #4
            [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0], #5
            [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], #6
            [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0], #7
            [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], #8
            [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]] #9
```

Comment: Olá, tem certeza que seus exemplos estão certos? As suas matrizes de adjacência nem são simétricas, o que gera ainda mais confusão. Dá uma olhadinha nesse link pra vc conferir se seus exemplos de matriz batem com a entrada https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_de_adjac%C3%AAncia